# How to resize the frame automatically based on the page content?

Tags: html, web, frame

I am creating the web page. I am new to this frame concept. I would like to resize the frame based on the page content. I saw many solution. Nothing is working. Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Give some context and show what you’ve tried so far. (By the way, it’s doubtful, whether this website behaviour is very user-friendly...)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. My home page height is 1000px; If i want to add the page which is having height of 1500px the height of my home page has to increase to 1500px. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to do it with a frame?